# Создание таблиц

Tags: html

Как сделать таблицу в html, чтобы первая строка была разделена на столбцы, а вторая нет?

Answer (score 3):

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4">LOOONG</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Пример:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LOOONG |

Answer (score 3):

Свойства **rowspan**, **colspan** вам в помощь! rowspan -> вертикаль, colspan -> горизонталь.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">1</td>
<td colspan="2">2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">7</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 9 |
| 7 |

Answer (score 0):

А можно не заморачиваться и прочитать всё это [здесь](http://zvirec.com/html_book.php?id=10).